Client request failure in raft
Imagine a 3 node raft cluster. Each node is in sync has log [1,2,3] and entry 3 is committed by the leader.
Now leader receives an entry 4 but fails to commit it because of unreliable network and returns a FAILED response to the client who made the request.
Post this, the client issues a request 5. Now when the leader tries to commit this entry, to follow log matching property, entry 4 will be replicated to majority as well and the leader would apply entry 4 and 5 to its state machine and increment the commit index.
But, this means that entry 4 would be applied by the state machine even though the client received a FAILED response.
Isn't this unexpected? Or am I missing something?
Some references along with your valuable answers that can clarify this answer would be much appreciated !

Could someone please help with this? Hoping for a reply!

This is the standard mode of operation. Failure means "not known outcome" and the client should make an extra step to discover the result, for example, the client could execute a linearizable read to see if 4 is in the commit log.
To clarify why the failure is interpreted as "unknown":

the leader received 4 from a client
the leader appended 4 to their own log
the leader sends 4 to each follower
the network drops
the leader does not know if 4 reached any of followers; the network could fail at any point so it is possible that no followers get the message, or some got the message, or majority got the message
either way, the leader reports failure to commit; and it's up to the client to find out the true outcome (e.g. to decide if they should send 4 one more time)

Edit based on comment:
"But, this means that entry 4 would be applied by the state machine even though the client received a FAILED response." - one of declared properties of Raft is that when an index is committed, it commits all previous indexes (4 in this case).
One more note: in this question, the leaders stays as the leader with the same term. Even without request 5, the leader will send the heart beat (ApplyEntries RPC) and 4th will be committed as the ApplyEntries call keeps replicating the difference between the leader and followers.
From client point of view, even if the client got failed, the record 4 will be committed and applied to each state machine.

The question talks about a different scenario, where the client issues request 5 and post that the leader commits request 4.

updated, thanks!

While this does describe what happens. Could you please share if this is expected?  How does a client ever know if its last operation would be committed in the future even if it received a failure right now?

Please, check https://raft.github.io/raft.pdf Section 8. The last paragraph is an example of no-op write; with this approach, the client may ask the leader if the last request was committed. The other example there (sequence number) is also a valid approach, but it requires Raft implementation to understand/implement sequence number support. Personally, I would rely on linearizable read. TL;DR - if a call to a leader failed, the client must interpret the failure as "I don't know what happened to last commit, it may or may not be committed"
